# Grafana displays garbage in Kafka Overview dashboard from Confluent

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, grafana

Hope to help someone with that as I have been struggling with this for a while.

I was setting up Grafana dashboard for Kafka metrics as described in https://www.confluent.io/blog/monitor-kafka-clusters-with-prometheus-grafana-and-confluent/

On one system created from scratch all metrics were displaying just fine:

[image]

While on other just garbage was displayed that made no sense and was changing with every refresh.

[image]

After making sure that I am using the same Grafana / Prometheus versions (without any change) I started to dig deeper.

What made mu wonder was that the graphs displaying garbage were having data source defined as "-Grafana-" while the one displaying properly were having "Prometheus", which should be the case.

That led me to final conclusion: On the system where the graphs were not displayed correctly Prometheus was defined as a data source, but was not tagged as default. After changing that and setting Prometheus as default data source everything was back to normal.

What is worth mentioning all the graphs displaying garbage were having "A-series" on X axis.

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Is there a question here, or did you figure out the problem? What you're seeing is Grafana's default "random walk" panel

Comment: Note that you can submit a PR to the Git repo where the dashboards are stored to set the default datasource